# Is there any way to get chrome driver executable file from nexus repository using maven for Automation project?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, automation, testng

I'm working on a Java-Selenium based Automation project where I have to run the tests on Google chrome. I don't want to have the binary executable file in the project folder. I know we can use Webdriver Manager(io.github.bonigarcia) dependency, but it is not allowed in our org. We are using Nexus repository to get the dependencies. So, is there any way to get OS compatible(such as windows, linux) and latest version of chrome driver from nexus repository?

Thanks in advance.